# session.storge for getting data from first page to another

Tags: java, html

I have a school project that tells me that I need to make 2 site's.

on The first site has to got a name on it can be in the code or by form doesn't really matter and it hast to have an link to the other site

the second site has to display that name with hello "name". And it has to show how many time's the person has been on that site.

I dint search for the visited time's one but that with the name I cant really find ! I know its easy to use `session.storage` or `local.storage` because the reader is telling me to search the internet for those commands but I cant find anything useful.

Comment: This sounds like a PHP question, I suggest changing the tags. You probably want a login form that stores a number to a database for the amount of successful logins. Or you could use cookies but this is unreliable.

Comment: no its a html 5 java thing its clearly in a <script> tag if i may do it with php i can do it in 5 min but that aint the case